# What adapter can I get to separate 3.5 mm mic+earphone bundled to mic AND earphone (2 cables)

Tags: audio, speakers, microphone

Right now, I have a Sony microphone+earphone 4-position plug. My PC has two separate ports for mic and speaker, so I have to buy a separate mic. It would be good to have a 4-position to 2x3position adapter so that:
Sony 4-position earphone -> split up to two cables (one for mic, one for speaker). Does there exist such adapter in the market?

Comment: Yes, you are looking for a 3.5mm mic+audio splitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answered yourself already:
searching on your favorite searchengine for "3.5mm 4-position to 2x 3-position splitter" should give you enough results.